# Scheme check between multiple strings

Tags: string, scheme, compare, racket

Out of practice to make myself more familiar with the scheme interface, I'm trying to write a procedure in Dr. Racket (though compatible with MIT Scheme) that checks between various different strings given and returns the appropriate strings depending on what is provided. What I have so far is this:

```
(define (conversation input)
    (cond ((eq? (or "hello Racket" "hi Racket" "what's up, Racket?" 
    "hey Racket" "what's happening, Racket?") input) "hey coder")
      (else "no hablo ingles.")))
```

*the space in between the strings is just so it will fit on here. It's one long statement in the interpreter.

The desired effect is that if I put in:

```
(conversation "hello Racket")
(conversation "hi Racket")
(conversation "hey Racket")
```

They will all return the same result, which is "hey coder". However, that is not what's happening. The only one that returns "hey coder" is (conversation "hello Racket"). All the rest return "no hable ingles." As with many other aspects of the language, I'm not all too savvy with strings in scheme. I'm fairly certain that the problem lies within the or statement, though I wouldn't know of the alternatives that would work in this context. I've tried looking up solutions, though I haven't run across anything that fits this type of description. Does anyone know of any alternatives to the code that would work?

Comment: Just as a note: treating `or` as if it can act distributively is a very common bug that beginners hit quite a lot.  The `or` in most programming languages is definitely not the same `or` as that used in natural human languages such as English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the effect that you intended using the [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._member%29%29) procedure and a list of possible options:

> `member` locates the first element of lst that is equal? to v. If such an element exists, the tail of lst starting with that element is returned. Otherwise, the result is #f.

This is what I mean:

```
(define (conversation input)
  (cond ((member input '("hello Racket" "hi Racket" "what's up, Racket?"
                         "hey Racket" "what's happening, Racket?"))
         "hey coder")
        (else "no hablo ingles.")))
```

Comment: that's actually what I ended up using. only difference really is that I defined the list externally and used an if rather than a cond. still, I think this idea works better than checking to see if they are all equal within one line.

Answer (score 3):

`or` takes a list of arguments and checks whether any of its arguments are "truthy" (that is not `#f`). If so, it returns the first of its arguments that is truthy. If not, it returns `#f`. So `(or "string1" "string2" ...)` simply returns "string1". So all you're doing is checking whether the given string equals "hello Racket" and ignoring the other options (you might object here that it doesn't work for "hello Racket" either - I'll get to that). What you want to be doing is to give whole conditions to `or`, not just the strings. So it should look like `(or (eq? "string1" input) (eq? "string2" input) ...)`.

However this doesn't work either. Why not? Because `eq?` is the wrong function to use to compare strings. It only returns true if two strings reside in the same location in memory. If two strings reside in different memory locations, but have the same contents, it returns `#f`. This is also why your current code returns `#f` for "hello Racket". What you should be using is `equal?`, which compares the contents of the strings.

This should work now, but it's a bit clunky - repeating the call to `equal?` for every possible string. A nicer approach would be to create a list with the valid strings and then check whether the input string is contained in the list using the `member` function.

Comment: the idea of using a list hadn't occurred to me, though I did have equal? originally. only thing is, I changed it to eq? because I was under the misguided impression that it was simply a shorthand form of equal? (shows how much I still need to practice). thanks for the clarification. I'm gonna give that a try

Comment: @dyoo Maybe I'm missing something, but how does what you just said differ from what I said in my answer?